Solving recurrence relation to find a generating function
Say I have the recurrence:
$a_t(u,v) = (a_t(u-1,v-1) + a_t(u-1,v)) q^{u-2v+t}$
with initial values:
$a_t(u,v) = 0$ for $u < 0 $ , $v < 0 $, or $v > L$.
Where $ L = \lfloor(u-t-1)/2\rfloor $ and $a_t(0,0) = q^t$.
I define the generating function $A_{t,u}(q)$ below. For context $A_{t,u}(q)$ gives in powers of $q$ all compositions (ordered partitions) with all adjacent differences in $\{-1,1\}$, having first part $t$, and $u$ parts.
$$A_{t,u}(q) = \sum_{v= 0}^{L} a_t(u,v)$$
Then from the recurrence, summing over $v$ to $L$ gives
$$A_{t,u}(q) = \sum_{v= 0}^{L} a_t(u-1,v-1) q^{u-2v+t} + \sum_{v= 0}^{L} a_t(u,v-1) q^{u-2v+t}$$
What would be the next step in solving for $A_{t,u}(q)$?

To me the generating function for the $a_t(u,v)$ would be $\sum_u \sum_v a_t(u,v) x^u y^v$.

What does $L < v < 0$ mean?.. If $L < 0$, then $A_{t,u}(q) = 0$ by definition, since it's an empty sum. And otherwise, the constraint doesn't make sense.

@OleksandrKulkov, you are right. What I meant here was if v<0 or v>L.

@GregMartin, yes maybe I need to find that generating function first. I see lower case a_t(u,v) as the single coefficient of (x^u) (y^v). Then capital A_{t,u} is the q expansion of the entire row of a_t(u,v).
